# Is there an equivalent of the cols attribute for tds?

Tags: html, css

Is there an equivalent of the cols attribute for tds?

Ex. (I know this doesn't work)

```
<td cols="40"> some text </td>
```

EDIT: sorry, I meant character limit per row =)

Comment: "equivalent" in which manner, what do want to achieve?

Comment: Ye, what do you mean? Btw, you can include code by selecting your code and clicking on the "Code Sample" button.

Comment: Hmmm, the code is there, is it not rendering?  It didn't render for me so I had to resubmit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean the `cols` attribute you can use in textarea element. This would be similar to the `width` attribute.

```
<td width="40">some text</td>
```

However, this is a **deprecated** attribute and should be done with styles.

Comment: what's the css equiv? style="width:40"?

Comment: Actually your solution is for pixels, I was looking for character count.

Comment: Yes, but setting the width, doesn't limit the characters per row—this depends on the font size. "I was looking for character count": thats not possible using pure CSS, you need any JavaScript char-counter, if want to have exact results, on how many characters go on one line.

Comment: So, what you are really looking for is an equivalent to the `maxlength` attribute; not the `cols`?